# Open URL or local file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, uri

I have a string.

I want:

- If this string is an URL, I want to open this URL.
- Otherwise, I want to open a local file with this name.
- If there is no such object, raise an exception.

What is the *correct* and easy enough (if possible) way to do it in Python 3?

The main issue is the correct way to determine if a string is an URL.

Comment: What is it is an invalid url (like "http://poo.gke") even though it follows url format? Should it be opened? Or checked by requests or other means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by URL. If it's a web address, it will most usually start with `http://` or `https://` (usually, those are the cases you care about, anyway). However, it is possible that is also starts with `ftp://` or some other protocol. However, most libraries accept *URI*s, which includes *file URI*. In that scheme, a file location looks like a URL that starts with `file://`, so you could pass your string, not caring whether it's a web address or a file, and the library will take care of it. There is no straight way of knowing whether the address is valid, but the library will throw an exception if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
import webbrowser
import requests
webbrowser.open(s) if os.path.isfile(s) or requests.get(s) else exec("raise Exception")
```

Answer (score -2):

This hasn't been tested, so treat it as psuedocode.

```
if s.startswith('http'):
    # Do something
elif os.path.isfile(s):
    file = open(s, 'r')
else:
    raise Exception
```